# Mongoose Js MongoDB GZip Response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Just another performance question. We have multi-tiered architecture.

We use mongoDB for cached contents. Works well for us currently.

We use mongoose js for connectivity and query in our api server.

My question is, does mongoose asks mongo to send the data through wire in an optimised way? (i.e accept-encoding: gzip,deflate)

Does mongoDB respond to accept-encoding through port 27017?

I presume accept-encoding is HTTP 1.1 protocol definition. In that case I assume that mongoose just query the mongodb without any compression.

Not sure how to test this, I just made some amateur benchmark and assumptions.

Combined Upload speed of MongoDB Server and Download speed of API Server is 1.3MB/s.

The data I am requesting is about 5MB size.

Including data processing in API server side the total processing time of this data is 4 Seconds.

Thats a lot of time!

Any help on how to further benchmark or do compression in mongoose! would be really helpful.

Many thanks,

Karthik

[image: My Application stack]

Comment: The wire protocol for MongoDB is not HTTP, but rather TCP/IP: http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to compress the data in TCP/IP similar to gzip?

Comment: Generally best solution is to send/request less data and optimize your queries.

Comment: Hummm, yes, I agree. Let me try reducing the amount of data. Thank you all.